# Too much "APP_NAME keep stopping" pop-ups

Tags: 9.0-pie, miui

*Note*: Some Android texts below are translated to English by me. So if something looks familiar to the text in English Android but do not match exactly, could you please highlight it to me.

I have **non-rooted** Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro MIUI Global 11.0.3.0 Android 9 PPR1.180610.011 (not mine, I am just helping for my relative).
It have started to produce pop-up windows with the following text: "*APP_NAME* keeps stopping"
First error (after each reboot) is from "Google Play Services" (and it cause the almost the biggest number of the errors). Then the same errors are coming from "App Vault" (almost the same amount as "Google Play Services" but I have disabled "App Vault"), "Security", "msa", "Google", "Emoji Keyboard", "Messaging", "Weather", "YouTube"...
The details of the error are the same for all errors and are placed below.

My assume that the problem was caused by the cache cleaning performed using MIUI Cleaner.

So I have started searching for the ways to fix this. I have read ma-a-a-any things.
I have found several suggestions to fix "Google Play Services" by cleaning cache but I cannot do it using the usual list of apps because it keep closing because of the same error.
I have tried `adb` but `adb shell pm clear com.google.android.gms` are refusing to work without `root` access.

Could you please at least suggest an idea how to deal with this.
Also the ideas how to disable (at least temporary) such pop-ups are also very welcomed.

Bonus question:
I have backed up the `Android` directory using the `file transfer` USB mode.
Also I have run `adb backup -all` but not all application was backed up.
I have seen some suggestions for rooted devices.
But maybe is there any other way to back up every application without `root`.
I know about some all-in-one toolsets that are needed to be installed.
However, I prefer enter the commands by myself than some third-party software installation if it is possible.

The details of the error message (I have kept border lines on both pictures):
[image: Page1]
[image: Page2]
[image: Page3]
[image: Page4]
[image: Page5]
[image: Page6]
[image: Page7]
[image: Page8]

(Sorry for the photo quality, I was fighting with the tons of the messages.)

**UPDATE 1**: Fighting with the errors I have managed to uninstall Google Market updates and clean its cache. Then the app list and app pages stop closing because of the errors. However the pop-up keeps appearing after all cleaning actions with "Google Play Services" :(

Answer (score 1):

Well try uninstalling the Google Play Store and Google Play Services's updates.
If you can't or it doesn't work, then you can try disabling the Google Play Services (and if it still shows it then the play store itself), and using the Aurora Store instead of the Play  Store.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, the list of apps and the app page keep closing. So I am not unable to uninstall updates or disable service there. `adb disable com.google.android.gms` does not work because of `SecurityException`.

Comment: See Update 1 in the question. I have tried to disable Google Play Service but there is no button "Disable", only "Close" (produced no effect).

Comment: @NickVeld Factory reset?

Comment: Before factory reset it is important to backup some application data but I still do not know how :(

Comment: @NickVeld use Google Drive's device backup feature. Look for it or do some research.

Comment: I have tried to enter into Google account in one app in order to enable cloud-synchronization. The app keeps failing because, I suppose, Google's internals are failing...